# Parse django template tag with custom filter for a live preview container via javascript

Tags: javascript, django, markup, live-preview

I need to create a **live preview** container (like stackoverflow and Reddit) for my **django** website using **[textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29)** as my markup language.

[image: live preview - Reddit]

Is there a way to do it on the client side? (without using ajax?)

Parsing the code from the view is as simple as:

```
{% load markup %}
{{ theme.content|textile }}
```

(Needless to say, I followed [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/) and included `'django.contrib.markup'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.)

For simplicity's sake, lets assume I don't need IE support. My JS looks as follows:

```
function change_preview() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    // I am no sure what should I put here:
    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode('{{ theme.content|textile }}'))
    document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(fragment);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var content_box = document.getElementById('id_content');
    content_box.addEventListener("input", change_preview , false );
}
```

And HTML:

```
<textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>
<div id = "preview"></div>
```

Also I found [this JS library](http://www.ben-daglish.net/textile.shtml). Is it a good idea to use it on the client-side together with [PyTextile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/textile) on the server-side?

What are the best practices?

I am looking for non-jQuery solutions, but I will accept one if there are no other ways to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since textile specifies what markup corresponds to what html I don't see a big potential for incompatibilities between a JS lib and a Py lib.

In your script for an immediate preview update you might want to use the `keyup` event instead of the `input` event since the latter is only fired when the `textarea` looses focus.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var content_box = document.getElementById('id_content');
    content_box.addEventListener("keyup", change_preview , false );
}
```

To use Ben Daglish's lib, which is not based on jQuery, your event handler would look like this:

```
function change_preview() {
    var content_box = document.getElementById('id_content');
    var html = convert(content_box.value);
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML=html;
}
```

Comment: So I was on the right track? I was hoping there is an easier solution, but I guess I would have to use a JS and a Python library after all. Thank you for your help.